# C# Performance Issue

Tags: performance, c#-3.0

I am facing a very strange situation and don't know how to solve it...Please help me solve the issue...

I am working on a web site where a research page is created to measure the performance of tasks done in the web site. It is one type of report page which checks for different conditions into the database tables, retrieves the information and send an email to the administrator. The page runs in every hour that is 24 times per day.

Now what the issue is: The web site works correctly however when the research page runs the other pages of the web site do not work correctly. That is say for example I am on the Page1 and at the same time the research page start running. Now at this time - when research page is running - if I click on the link of Page2, the Page2 will not get displayed until research page finishes its working. Can anyone tell what could be the issue for this behavior?

Here are some more information regarding the issue:

- The web site is in Visual Studio 2008 (C#) and SOL Server 2008 is
  used
- The SOL query is too complex for research page however, I have made
  all the optimization which are possible.
- There are two connection strings (with different user for same
  database) used in the web site. One for the Research page and second
  for all the other pages in the site

Please help me find out the issue... Thanks in advance....

Comment: You really need to post your code for us to even start to guess. What isolation level is the query running in? Are you locking tables? Why use the same database for OLTP and reporting?

Comment: I don't know about the isolation level....Regarding locking tables I am not using any locks......This is a just one page which is used like report page but not a report page......

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to mishandling of the Thread within you website. Have you tried it by Threads and Building Asynchronous Handlers in Your Server-Side Web Code

**Just check out this might help you with :**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx

[msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx)

http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx

And also do take care of releasing the necessary resources which might be locks up the Table, even though the Thread function gets over.